# Insert symbol on edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, currency

I have two editText :

```
prix = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.prix);
```

edittext (prix) and I would like to insert €, after the number as 10€

```
remise = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.remise);
```

edittext (remise) and I would like to insert %, after the number as 10%

I would like to use Textwatcher but I don't understand it in my case.